# Can't create MYSQL table for Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to create a table in my database to store my Wordpress plugin settings. I'm using the code below, but it doesn't work. I don't get any errors but the table is not created, and it seems that the function is not executed at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function ADR_create()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "Author_detailed_repport";
    global $charset_collate;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    global $db_version;

    if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE ".$table_name ) !=  $table_name)
    {   $create_sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . "(
            ADR_id INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
            role VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            statut INT(1) NOT NULL,
            post_number INT(4) NOT NULL,
            activate INT(1) NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE (ADR_id) )$charset_collate;";

    }

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta( $create_sql );
    if (!isset($wpdb->Author_detailed_repport))
    {
        $wpdb->Author_detailed_repport = $table_name;
        //add the shortcut so you can use $wpdb->stats
        $wpdb->tables[] = str_replace($wpdb->prefix, '', $table_name);
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ADR_create');
```

Answer (score 0):

i have fix the problem, there is nothing wrong with this code, i was just typing it in the wrong file